# How do I create a chart with two lines, using grouping?

Tags: salesforce-classic, group-by, report-chart

What I have: revenue data, summarized by calendar month. I have created a custom summary formula that totals the revenue for that month.

Over all data, I have created a second grouping, based on a custom checkbox field. So the data is shown in two groups and within these two groups the data is shown per month. The resulting report, as numerical data, is exactly how I want it to be.

Next, I want to have a chart with two lines. X-axis is time (the calendar months), Y-axis is revenue. For each value of the custom checkbox field I want a line, so two lines in total.

When I create the chart, I can choose: Y-axis, X-axis and Group By. For all of these, I can choose exactly the fields that I want to choose. And then... the chart says: 'The report returned no results'. When in fact, there are results, they are right there on the screen!

How do I do this? I have experience with Salesforce charts, I know that charts and groups can be bothersome, so I was pleasantly surprised that I could choose the grouping. But it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. After some googling, it turns out that I had used the wrong report type. I had used Summary, but I should have used Matrix. Then I had to recreate the custom summary function (it was deleted after the change in report type). After I had changed that, the chart worked.